# Get a <span> value using python web scrape

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get a product price using BeautifulSoup in python.
But i keep getting erroes, no matter what I try.

[The picture of the site i am trying to web scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFSVB.png)

I want to get the 19,90 value.
I have already done a code to get all the product names, and now need their prices.

```
    import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.zattini.com.br/busca?nsCat=Natural&q=amaro&searchTermCapitalized=Amaro&page=1'

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

price = soup.find('span', itemprop_='price')

print(price)
```

Comment: Did you check whether you already have expected html content, because the website said that i dont have permission to access.  But if you have full page, try `soup.find('span', {itemprop:'price'})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`span[itemprop='price']` is generated by javascript. Original value stored in `div[data-final-price]` with value like `1990` and you can format it to `19,90` with Regex.

```
import re

...
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
prices = soup.select('div[data-final-price]')
for price in prices:
    price = re.sub(r'(\d\d$)', r',\1', price['data-final-price'])
    print(price)
```

Results:

```
19,90
134,89
29,90
119,90
104,90
59,90
....
```

Answer (score 2):

Less ideal is parsing out the JSON containing the prices

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.zattini.com.br/busca?nsCat=Natural&q=amaro&searchTermCapitalized=Amaro&page=1'
page = requests.get(url)    
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
scripts = [script.text for script in soup.select('script') if 'var freedom = freedom ||' in script.text]
pricesJson = scripts[0].split('"items":')[1].split(']')[0] + ']'
prices = [item['price'] for item in  json.loads(pricesJson)]
names = [name.text for name in soup.select('#item-list [itemprop=name]')]
results = list(zip(names,prices))

df = pd.DataFrame(results)
print(df)
```

Sample output:

[image]